# Double from unsigned int[2]?

Tags: c

I have a 64-bit number written as two 32-bit unsinged ints: `unsigned int[2]`. `unsigned int[0]` is MSB, and `unsigned int[1]` is LSB. How would I convert it to `double`?

`double d_from_u2(unsigned int*);`

Comment: Are you asking how to transfer the bits of your two `unsigned int`s into a `double`, or does "written as" have some other implication for the needed conversion?

Comment: John, just transfer.

Comment: `typedef union { unsigned int iVar[2]; double dVar; } i2d;` ?

Comment: Does unsigned int[0] and [1] denote a 64 bit integral value, or is the representation already a floating point representation (and for some mystic reason split in two 4-byte-chunks)?

Comment: We know the ordering of the two `unsigned int`s within the array is big-endian, but is the ordering of the bytes within each `unsigned int` also big-endian? And what is the endian-ness of the host CPU? What I'm getting at is that you may or may not need to do some byte swapping.

Comment: The real question here is how you know that the data in those unsigned ints is an exact binary representation of a double. And the next question then is, why would you use `int` to store it, since that makes the code endianess dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to copy the bits of your two integers into an object of type `double`.

At the lowest level, you can convert your input pointer to a [`unsigned`] `char *`, create a  [`unsigned`] `char *` to the first byte of the return value, and copy between those by whatever means you choose.  This provides you every opportunity to adjust byte order as may be needed -- for example, although your array is ordered most-significant *word* first, the order of the bytes within those words might not be what you need.

In the event that you need the bytes to be transferred into your `double` most-significant byte first, and that you do not want to depend on the machine byte order, you might do this:

```
double d_from_u2(unsigned int *in) {
    double result;
    unsigned char *result_bytes = (unsigned char *) &result;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        result_bytes[i] =     in[0] >> (24 - 8 * i);
        result_bytes[i + 4] = in[1] >> (24 - 8 * i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Using arithmetic (shifts, in this case) allows you to operate on the numeric values of the input independently of details of numeric representation.

Answer (score 5):

`memcpy` it from your source array to a `double` object in proper order. E.g. if you want to swap the `unsigned` parts

```
unsigned src[2] = { ... };
double dst;
assert(sizeof dst == sizeof src);

memcpy(&dst, &src[1], sizeof(unsigned));
memcpy((unsigned char *) &dst + sizeof(unsigned), &src[0], sizeof(unsigned));
```

Of course, you can always just reinterpret both source and destination objects as arrays of `unsigned char` and copy them byte-by-byte in any order you wish

```
unsigned src[2] = { ... };
double dst;

unsigned char *src_bytes = (unsigned char *) src;
unsigned char *dst_bytes = (unsigned char *) &dst;

assert(sizeof dst == 8 && sizeof src == 8);

dst_bytes[0] = src_bytes[7];
dst_bytes[1] = src_bytes[6];
...
dst_bytes[7] = src_bytes[0];
```

(The second example is not intended to be equivalent to the first one.)

Comment: Can't use `memcpy`, sorry.

Comment: @Danijel: Firstly, Weird limitations should normally be mentioned in the question... Is there anything else that you "can't use"? Secondly, if you can't use `memcpy` you can always spell it out manually, explicitly. It is just a simple cycle that copies `n` bytes. You can even express it without a cycle, as byte-by-byte copying.

Comment: not really important to the correctness of the answer, but I'd make that `assert` into a `static_assert` (assuming C11 and all those good stuff).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works without `memcpy`but using `union`:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"

double d_from_u2(unsigned int* v) {
  union { 
    int32_t x[2];
    int64_t y;
  } u = { .x = { v[1], v[0] }};

  printf("%llu\n", u.y); // 1311768467463794450

  return (double)u.y;
}

int main(void) {
  int32_t x[2];

  x[0] = 0x12345678;
  x[1] = 0x9abcef12;
  printf("%f\n", d_from_u2(x)); // 1311768467463794432.000000
  return 0;
}
```

See [demo](https://repl.it/FcDn/2). In initializes the array `int32_t[2]` in the union and uses the `int64_t` to convert it to a `double`. The order of the initialization depends on which machine (little or big endian) it runs or where the values comes from ([1](https://repl.it/FcDn/2) first).